# Using mkdir -m -p and chown together correctly

Tags: linux, bash, sh, mkdir

I would like to create a directory using a bash script and then set the mode to 00755 at the same time

```
mkdir -p -m=00755 "/dir/dir2"
```

Is this the correct way of using them together and can I also add chown command to the same line while creating them?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

It goes a little like this:

```
install -d -m 0755 -o someuser -g somegroup /dir/dir2
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. Is it possible to give the parent directory "/dir/" the same owner and group instead of just "/dir2/"?

Comment: You may have to pass both of them on the command line, e.g. `install -d ... /dir /dir/dir2`.

Comment: I got the following error trying to create /dir directory with `install -d -m 0755 -o 1000 -g 1000 /`: `install: cannot change owner and permissions of ‘/dir’: No such file or directory`. I thought the idea was to create a directory, and change the owner, in the same command?

Comment: I had grown tired of `mkdir` followed by `chown`.

Comment: @SeanMcCarthy You might have to use `sudo`. Since owner is being changed, the command requires it.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to set the owner during creation, you can simply impersonate as this user, using `sudo` for example:

```
sudo -uTHE_USER mkdir -p -m=00755 "/dir/dir2"
```

This has the advantage that there will be no time difference between creation and changing the ownership, which could otherwise being harmful if exploited.

Comment: That doesn't work if you want to create a directory owned by `THE_USER` under a directory where `THE_USER` doesn't have write access.

Comment: You didn't mentioned that in your question, but you are right. I would break the operation into two single creations then.

Comment: To be clear, it wasn't my question, and I don't know whether the OP needs that functionality or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that should work. As for the chown, simply follow the command ' && chown...  '. && is similar to ; except the next command *ONLY* executes if the previous command exits success (0).

Comment: Not at all atomic -- meaning there exists a moment in time when the directory is owned by the wrong user. Granted, short of the approach given by @hek2mgl, that's hard to address, and if the initial user is one which untrusted processes have no access to, it's not necessarily harmful. I'd have to look at the implementation of `install` to know whether it has the same issue.