# Invocation of install for creating also parents with specified owner, group

Tags: bash

When I create a directory [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873479/using-mkdir-m-p-and-chown-together-correctly) (as `root`)

```
install -d -o my_user -g my_group parent/child/grandchild
```

in a situation where only directory `parent` exists, this will create a directory 
`parent/child/grandchild` where grandchild is owned by `my_user:my_group`, but
`child` is owned by `root:root`.

Can I invoke `install` in such a way that both newly created directories are owned
by `my_user:my_group`, or would this require several calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have concluded that this unfortunately requires two calls to `install` like so:

```
install -d -o my_user -g my_group parent/child
install -d -o my_user -g my_group parent/child/grandchild
```